# Is it stable to install GNOME 3.8 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, gnome

I have installed KDE on my Ubuntu 12.04 before, and it worked fine for me until I tried to update it. When I tried to update, the Ubuntu Software Center broke, and I can't install anything.

I have asked this on this site but no one answered it. Then I have installed Ubuntu 13.04, and I want to know is it safe and stable to install  GNOME 3.8 on my Ubuntu?

Comment: If you prefer Gnome Shell, try installing [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/). Well, notice that Gnome 3.8 is not in the official repos, so the logical conclusion is that it is not a stable setup (unless you uninstall/upgrade Unity, thus it'd be better to just install Ubuntu GNOME).

Comment: Every PPA in Launchpad has this warning "You can update your system with **unsupported packages** from this **untrusted** PPA..."

Comment: no i asked about installing (adding) Gnome to Ubuntu 13.04 , I checked Ubuntu Gnome site & i don't want just gnome with even no Ubuntu software center & Firefox ! , I want to have choice to select between gnome & Ubuntu in Ubuntu 13.04 start screen (like the way Ubuntu 12.04 was)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been running Gnome-shell 3.8 from the Gnome3 Team PPA (https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) for a number of months now without issue.

If you already have gnome-shell installed, then running the following commands should upgrade to 3.8:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

OMG! Ubuntu! has a detailed article on installing Gnome 3.8 in Ubuntu: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/gnome-3-8-ppa-for-ubuntu-gnome

Comment: thanks , I need something like this (a user that tested before) but i haven't installed gnome-shell manually yet.

Comment: but in the above link (OMG! Ubuntu!) many users have issues !

Comment: I've tested this before, it broke my Unity desktop.

Comment: i have installed it 5 days ago & it causes some (small) issues in my Unity desktop , but gnome is working perfect ! (THANKS)