# How to Install Gnome 3.8 on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, gnome

I'm new to this ubuntu 13.04 so can any one help me installing Gnome 3.8 on my ubuntu 13.04 clearly step-by-step please.

Comment: Similar or the same question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/327621/is-it-stable-to-install-gnome-3-8-on-ubuntu-13-04?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and enter line per line:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: No i want to install Gnome shell freshly in my laptop this command is to used to update Gnome shell if your using older version of it.

Comment: Then just use `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`